# cordova callback inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, iframe

I created some Android web application using cordova and nanohttpd. The main page is loaded from nanohttp with localhost url. The main page contains an iFrame which load some page from same domain as main page (localhost).

The code below is called from an iFrame :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    cordova.exec(function(response) {           
        self.doSomething(response);
    },function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    },"thePlugin","showMap", param);}, false);
```

Now this is my problem : the cordova.exec from iframe is able to call Java plugin and show the map. But it is not able to find the javascript callback function. Is it possible to fire the callback function inside iFrame? If its possible, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is very possible.

Your problem is caused by the conflicts between the main window and the iframe window.

Please refer to this link:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/iFrame-Usage

I have successfully implemented this using cordova plugin contact android.

To make it possible, you need to do these:

1. Create the communication between parent window and the child/iframe using **postMessage**. Parent and child listen each other.
2. Send/trigger the message from child/iframe to parent to call the cordova plugin.
3. Call the cordova plugin from **parent window**.
4. Create the **global function** in **parent window** to be called from the **cordova code/side** (Java in android).
5. Find out the java file in cordova that (call the callback function and parse the result back). **Clue: callbackContext.success(parameter);**. From here, we need to call the **global function** created in parent window.
6. Call the **global function** created in parent window from the java file of cordova. Here is the snippet of calling js code from java code:

> **your_web_view**.loadUrl("javascript:**function_name**(**parameter_result_from_cordova**)");

7. Send back the message gotten in parent to the iframe/child using postMessage.

This should work. Let me know if you find any issue.

Comment: Thank you! Let me try this.

Comment: Update: this is working most of the time. But there is a chance, sometimes like 1 out of 4, that Cordova callback is not executed.

Comment: Right, It sometimes still calls the wrong receiver context. I have updated the answer. The point is we need to do a little modification in the cordova plugin side by calling the javascript function directly after getting the result. I have implemented it and it should work like a charm.

Comment: Ah yes! Injecting the result straight to javascript is working perfectly. Thanks a lot Ratih!